# one of my web hostings is down - only for me - why?

Tags: networking, web-server, web-hosting, routing, website

My first post here, I am reading / learning a lot, thanks ;).

I've got a mysterious issue (for me) and would really appreciate to get it solved.

I've rent a reseller package with bibihost.com and it's now the second time that

- all my domaines
- the hoster's site

are unavailable from my connection (my Mac and my iPhone), (in browser, per FTP, ping, ab, and traceroute)
This has never before happened to me with other web addresses.

traceroute get's always stuck at a specific server

40g.vss-1-6k.routers.chtix.eu (91.121.131.29)

The sites are all up for everyone else, I've checked with downforeveryoneorjustme.com, a homegrown script loaded to another server and montastic.com

My question(s) :

- Why am I blocked ?
- Is there anything I can do about it ?

If I cannot solve this issue I have to change the hoster, but I really would like to know what's going on.

my domaines on this server :

- tienstiens.fr
- tomlegrand.com

Answer (score 1):

it's obviously your ip get blocked in that router.

as silviot said, might be you have suspicious connection.
maybe you do too much connect-disconnect. and might also be your pc get infected with some malware doing the bad connection you do not know.

are you getting  public ip from your ISP? is it static or dynamic?
if you're on private ip (192.168.x.x or 172.16.x.x or 10.x.x.x) then you might share same public ip with dozens or maybe hundreds of other pc. then, the problem might caused by other pc you have no control of...

talked with your host is the only way to know.
it's their network. they can investigate from their site.

meanwhile, check your pc for malware, open proxy, etc...

Comment: DennyHalim, silviot, thanks, indeed I had been blocked by the hoster, have it fixed by now, w/o explication, though.

Answer (score 0):

You probably somehow triggered a ban from your IP address. Some activity you have done has been seen as "suspicious".

This is something you should discuss with bibihost.com.

Usually this kind of ban is temporary (expect some hours/some days).

In the meanwhile you can use a proxy if you need access to your sites.